# Azure Functions v3, Dotnet Core v3.1 EF core /EF Core SQL 3.1.x No Errors no Data from SQL in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

- using this image `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0`. Running on baremetal kubernetes or local docker I get no errors but also no data from SQL Server. I am using the RabbitMq trigger to start the function on received message. The function is async and I use `FunctionsStart` in my startup.cs. I have confirmed the environment variable is set and correct at runtime. The context is not used directly in the function but is use by another IService that I inject.
- Note - The code runs just fine in the debug emulator, connection and data return without issues. Also runs just fine with I remove EF and the MyDbContext.

  ```
      builder.Services
          .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_DB")))
  ```

Note sure if this warning is related to the issue. 
`warn: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService[0]
      Breaking change analysis operation failed
System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_CodeBase()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService.LogBreakingChangeReport(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/BreakingChangeAnalysis/ChangeAnalysisService.cs:line 140
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService.TryLogBreakingChangeReportAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/BreakingChangeAnalysis/ChangeAnalysisService.cs:line 103
[14:39:30 WRN] Breaking change analysis operation failed
System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.
   at System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder.get_CodeBase()
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService.LogBreakingChangeReport(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/BreakingChangeAnalysis/ChangeAnalysisService.cs:line 140
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ChangeAnalysis.ChangeAnalysisService.TryLogBreakingChangeReportAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/BreakingChangeAnalysis/ChangeAnalysisService.cs:line 103`

Comment: Are you logging errors or getting any error? Check trace & error logs to confirm if application ran fully or got broken somewhere

Comment: Logging errors using Trace for the function. In the log the context starts up connects, end of log.